# Drupal Module Themes - Default CSS?

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal-modules

There's tons of documentation out there on how to override the appearance of Drupal modules, but I keep finding the docs for writing the *original* theme to be a little lacking.  On this note, how can I tell Drupal to use a specific CSS file for my custom module's block output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a custom css for your module, in your module code (rather than the theme), by using `drupal_add_css`. Example from `hook_init` in admin_menu module:

```
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'admin_menu');
drupal_add_css($path .'/admin_menu.css', 'module', 'all', FALSE);
```

If you just want custom css at the theme level, then add a reference to the css path in your theme's .info file.

Answer (score 0):

For blocks, you may find good use in the block class module.

http://drupal.org/project/block_class

If your module is outputting a block, it should have an ID from block.tpl.php output which is prime for overriding. You can also assign a class or ID scheme from your module which will also assist in theming.

Comment: I don't want to override! I'm trying to implement a default theme for the block, not in a separate site-wide theme.

Comment: Whatever theme you are using should have baseline css defined for blocks.. and thats the theme. To change it you have to override it or change the CSS. That or I don't fully understand your question. You can add more stylesheets to your theme with drupal_add_css and _preprocess functions in template.php